# DataGridView - Retain cell changes when navigating with Tab/Arrow Keys/Mouse

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

In a VB.NET project I'm building in VS2013 I have some DataGridViews in which, currently only moving to a new cell with the **Enter** key will retain the previous cell's changes when the Save button is clicked. If the user moves to a new cell using the Tab key, the Arrow keys or mouse-clicking anywhere outside of the cell the change isn't retained.

Put another way: if after editing a cell, the user navigates to another cell by using the **Enter** key, when the Save button is clicked the edited value is saved to the database, but if, after editing a cell, the user navigates to another cell with any of the other methods (arrow, tab, etc), when the Save button is clicked the edited value is **not** saved. It's as if using the Enter key is the only way that the edit value is "committed" to the SqlDataAdapter, which is what I'm using to write to the SQL database that the DGV gets its data from.

I've been watching the CellEndEdit, CellLeave, and CellValidating events and I'm not seeing why it's just using the Enter key that the changed value is retained.

How can I make it so that navigating with mouse, arrows, tab will keep the changes too?

Comment: Please clarify: When you edit a cell then `Tab`, `Arrow`, or `MouseClick` another cell the edited value is reverted?  Or do you mean the edited value remains but when clicking `Save`, it is only saved when the user hit `Enter` to leave that cell?

Comment: Better yet, can you provide a minimum working example to reproduce the error?

Comment: @OhBeWise, I added a paragraph (2nd one) with a more detailed explanation of how the different ways to leave an edited cell affect whether the edit value is saved. I don't have time right now to put together an example, sorry. If you (or anyone else) can provide an answer/suggestion with the provided information, it would be greatly appreciated!